# batch to extract part of text file containing a keyword between two strings

Tags: batch-file

Say, i have a text file **test.txt** as below:

> ee
>
> eee
>
> aaaaa
>
> aaaaa
>
> bbbb
>
> **546**
>
> iiiii
>
> fffffff
>
> qq
>
> aaaaa
>
> qqq
>
> aaaaa
>
> bbbb
>
> **123**
>
> iiiii
>
> fffffff

suppose numbers which are marked bold is called as **ID** then i need part of file between the first aaaaa which appears just before **ID-123** and first fffffff which appears after the **ID-123**

i.e Output:

> aaaaa
>
> bbbb
>
> **123**
>
> iiiii
>
> fffffff

Can it be done using batch?

Comment: Your sample data and description don't give enough information, unless you want to find "123" and 4 lines above and 4 lines below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT***: I modified the program below in order to fulfill these additional requirements:

1- Extract all sections that match the parameters, separated by an empty line.

2- Store the result in the file given by second parameter and .txt extension

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

if "%~3" equ "" (
   echo FindSection.bat sectionStart middleKeyword sectionEnd
   goto :EOF
)

set lastStart=
set start=
set i=0
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "%~1 %~2 %~3" test.txt') do (
   if "%%b" equ "%~1" (
      set lastStart=%%a
   ) else if "%%b" equ "%~2" (
      set start=!lastStart!
   ) else if "%%b" equ "%~3" (
      if defined start (
         set /A i+=1
         set /A start[!i!]=start, end[!i!]=%%a
         set lastStart=
         set start=
      )
   )
)
if %i% equ 0 (
   echo Section not found
   goto :EOF
)
set /A i+=1
set /A start[%i%]=0x7FFFFFFF, end[%i%]=0x7FFFFFFF
set /A i=1, start=start[1], end=end[1]
(for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" test.txt') do (
   if %%a gtr !end! (
      set /A i+=1
      set /A start=start[!i!], end=end[!i!]
   )
   if !start! leq %%a if %%a leq !end! echo(%%b
   if %%a equ !end! echo/
)) > "%~2.txt"
```

For example:

```
C:> FindSection aaaaa 123 fffffff

C:> type 123.txt
aaaaa

bbbb

123

iiiii

fffffff
```

Comment: it worked for first aaaaa(sectionStart) which appears before 123(middleKeyword) but having a problem with sectionEnd. If i put abcd fffffff in the end of the file, it will print them too coz it is taking the sectionEnd as last fffffff not the one appears just after 123...Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Aacini!!! It worked like charm. one small doubt, how to store the result in a text file giving it's name same as the ID i.e middleKeyword :)..and i figured one more thing that is when we have 123 multiple times or same set of text again it gives result for the first one only..m a bit confused..newbie to batch so its time for me to understand batch commands.

Comment: @D.A.: What do you want to do in this case? Show all the sections that match the parameters? Separated by an empty line, perhaps? This is the type of "thing" that may require a substantial modification of the program, so you always should post complete requirements from the very beginning! Your first additional request was the output in middleKeyword file, and now this one. Are you sure that this is your last request? I don't like to do modifications in several small steps!

Comment: Ya, store all the sections that match the parameters separated by an empty line in a text file. And yes this is my last request to you for sure.Thanks to you for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, batch solution:

```
@echo off &SETLOCAL
FOR /f "delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /n "123" "test.txt"') DO SET /a match=%%a
SET /a first=match-2
SET /a last=match+2
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /n "^" "test.txt"') DO (
    IF %%a geq %first% IF %%a leq %last% ECHO %%b
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) for Windows:

```
grep -A2 -B2 "123" test.txt
```

Comment: maybe this? `grep -A4 -B4 "123" test.txt`  I assume the blank lines are part of the data.

Comment: @foxidrive thank you. The OP should explain better his file format, he posted it in "quoting format".